# Outputting to console from Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

im creating a hangman game that has to use CHAR and not strings. I was wondering how i would choose a single random word form a Char array and display it to the console as a symbol e.g. ****** instead of the word. My current array; Thank you.

```
char words [6][10] =
{
    "Pistachio",
    "Avocado",
    "Salami",
    "Bologna",
    "Christmas",
    "Giraffes",
};
```

This is what i have so far (i know it not much im a bit confused)

```
cout <<"Test " <<words <<endl;
```

and that just out put a random number ??

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I strongly recommend going through at least a basic C tutorial...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
#include<cstdlib>


int v;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    v = rand() %6;
    printf("%s\n", words[v]);
}
```

Comment: do i declare v as an integer

Answer (score 0):

To output a cstring from an array of cstrings you need to provide the index of that string.

```
cout <<"Test " <<words <<endl;
```

Will just print the address of the first element of the array since that is what an array name is reduced to.  So the correct way to display from the array is:

```
cout <<"Test " <<words[indexOfTheStringYouWant] <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`words` is <del>a `char**`</del> an array of `char[10]`. The `<<` operator knows how to print simple types (int, float), std::string and `char *`, but not <del>`char **`</del> arrays nor pointers to C strings (char arrays). So it only print the address of the array of <del>`char *`.</del> `char[10]`

I think that what you want is :

```
for (int i=0; i< sizeof(words)/sizeof(char *); i++) cout << words[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Comment: `words` is an array of arrays. It decays to a pointer to an array, `char(*)[10]`, not to a `char**`.

Comment: You are right ... I read to quickly what I always use `char *words[] = {...}` that would decay to a `char **`.

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


int main()
{
    const size_t N = 6;
    const size_t M = 10;
    char words[N][M] =
    {
        "Pistachio",
        "Avocado",
        "Salami",
        "Bologna",
        "Christmas",
        "Giraffes",
    };
    size_t index[N];

    std::iota( index, index + N, 0 );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::random_shuffle( index, index + N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << words[index[i]] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Giraffes
Bologna
Pistachio
Avocado
Salami
Christmas
```